# Flask python - POST not working as expected

Tags: python, rest, flask

I am learning RESTFUL APIs and I am stuck at a problem which only issues request for GET but fails for POST request. The code goes here:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
#Make an app.route() decorator here
@app.route("/puppies", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def puppiesFunction():
    if request.method == 'GET':
    #Call the method to Get all of the puppies
        return getAllPuppies()

    elif request.method == 'POST':
    #Call the method to make a new puppy
        return makeANewPuppy()

def getAllPuppies():
    return "Getting All the puppies!"

def makeANewPuppy():
    return "Creating A New Puppy!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.debug = True
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

The GET request works fine but error coming up in POST request. The error is:

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2016 01:39:34] "POST /puppies/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *What* error do you get?

Comment: How do you do POST request? 404 is not found error. Try /puppies instead of /puppies/ and try to split methods, maybe it will work.

Comment: For me the code works fine. Try curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:5000/puppies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your POST request has an extra slash at the end of the URL. Here are the curl commands:

```
$ curl -X POST 0.0.0.0:5000/puppies
Creating A New Puppy
$ curl -X POST 0.0.0.0:5000/puppies/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

And here are the Flask logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2016 11:17:12] "POST /puppies HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2016 11:17:20] "POST /puppies/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

And indeed in your question you used `/puppies/`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine, not sure what the problem is. i copy pasted your code as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/puppies", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def puppiesFunction():
    if request.method == 'GET':
    #Call the method to Get all of the puppies
        return getAllPuppies()

    elif request.method == 'POST':
    #Call the method to make a new puppy
        return makeANewPuppy()

def getAllPuppies():
    return "Getting All the puppies!"

def makeANewPuppy():
    return "Creating A New Puppy!"

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

[image]

and the post requests is working as expected. here is what I did using fiddler:
[image]